# Is it possible to jump longer in Limbo?

Tags: xbox-360, limbo

I've just started to play Limbo, and I wonder if there is a key combination to jump longer rather than the usual jump with a single key stroke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been playing the game for the last few days, and I've found out that there are two types of jumps:

1. **Normal jump**: You push and immediately release the jump button (A).
2. **Longer jump**: You push and hold the jump button (A) for about a second.

There are some parts in the game where you have to use the *Longer Jump*. Otherwise, it becomes impossible to pass that level.

You can test the *normal jump* and the *longer jump* on a flat horizontal surface. I usually use the *longer jump* for convenience.

Comment: Also, jumping while running makes you go further than jumping from a standing start. Pretty obvious I know.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to boost your jump distance in Limbo.

This is a deliberate feature made to increase the difficulty of the puzzles, by forcing the player to think of more strategic solutions than "just jump over it".

Answer (score -2):

If you are playing on IOS and you are at the first pit, you have to run down the little bit of space you have, and then jump. Getting up to the edge and jumping won't work. It takes some practice to keep your finger on the screen to get him to run and then jump, but it will work.